# Impact of increased sodium conductance at a neuromuscular junction

Tags: neuroscience, neurophysiology, muscles, neurotransmitter, action-potential

If trans-epithelial Na+ transport were to increase at the synapse(please consider both pre and post-synaptic membrane situations) in a neuromuscular junction, how would that manifest itself? My guess is that the increased sodium conductance would depolarize the membrane to a higher resting potential.

- Would this translate to higher firing rate or result in more frequency of miniature end-plate potentials?
- Would this also affect the rise time of action potential? Or its threshold?